# Как правильно обрабатывать событие Click в WinForms? C#

Tags: c#, winforms, события, click

Есть форма `Form1` и одна единственная кнопка `button1`

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //do something..
    }
```

Задумался над тем как правильно обрабатывать событие `Click`, в том плане, что не просто писать кучу кода вместо `do something`, а сделать это по крайней мере в стиле ООП. **Вопрос 1. Подскажите пожалуйста, как решают этот вопрос при разработке коммерческих программ?**

Сейчас я делаю примерно так

```
//Файл Form1.cs
private Department department = new Department();
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        department.Add += (obj, ev) =>
        {
                Task task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                {
                    //do something..
                });
        };

        department.Adding(Employees.Engineer);
}
//Файл Department.cs
class Department
{
    public delegate void DepartmentHandler(object sender, DepartmentEventArgs e);

    public event DepartmentHandler Add;

    public void Adding(Employees employee)
    {
        Add?.Invoke(this, new DepartmentEventArgs(employee));
    }
}

class DepartmentEventArgs: EventArgs
{
    public readonly Employees _employee;
    public DepartmentEventArgs(Employees employee)
    {
        _employee = employee;
    }
}
```

Я думаю суть понятна. **Вопрос 2. Подскажите пожалуйста, правильно ли я делаю, написав код таким образом?**

Всем большое спасибо за ответы!

Comment: При каждом нажатии на кнопку добавляется подписка на событие `Add`. А где отписка? Имхо, бред какой-то.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, Не будьте так категоричны. Представьте, что эта кнопка только добавляет данные в базу. Мой вопрос в том, правильно ли я организовываю обработку нажатия на кнопку. Если нет, не могли бы вы показать как правильно?

Comment: Для winforms обычно следуют шаблону `MVP` => Model-View-Presenter. То, что вы пытаетесь сделать в классе  `Department` c  `department.Add()` делают в классе презентера.  Класс презентера подписывается на события из вьюшки, которая реализует IMyView.

Comment: @Bulson, Можно вас попросить предложить какой-нибудь пример в качестве ответа (в идеале) или ссылку на гитхаб? Я плюсану :)

Comment: Попробую поискать пример.

Comment: @Bulson, Заранее большое спасибо!

Comment: Посмотрите простейший пример на этом  [видео](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N6RNy3rPZpg&index=8&list=PLWCoo5SF-qAMDIAqikhB2hvIytrMiR5TC). Это очень простой пример, но с него можно начать и его легко понять.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В [этом видео](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N6RNy3rPZpg&index=8&list=PLWCoo5SF-qAMDIAqikhB2hvIytrMiR5TC) дается самый простой пример MVP, без привязок и с простейшей переброской событий от кнопок в `Presenter`. Если вы начнете писать что-то более серьезное, то быстро осознаете необходимость работы с привязками, потому стоит внимательно ознакомиться с классом [BindingSource](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/bindingsource-component).

По существу заданного вопроса хочу дать несколько примеров, как можно события обернуть в свойства через классы посредников.

**1) Пример на простейшее событие выбора в `ComboBox`**
[image: пример выбора в комбобоксе и вывод выбранного в окне сообщенй]

Создадим такой класс, который потом будет использовать для создания свойства в форме

```
public class SimpleEventHandler
{
    private Action _handlerExecutor;

    //ctor
    public SimpleEventHandler(Action handlerExecutor)
    {
        _handlerExecutor = handlerExecutor ??
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(handlerExecutor));

        Handler = new EventHandler(OnEvent);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Ссылка на метод,
    /// который буден вызван при возникновении события у целевого контрола 
    /// </summary>
    public EventHandler Handler { get; private set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Вызов по событию исполняемого метода
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    private void OnEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _handlerExecutor();
    }
}
```

Тогда вьюшка будет такой

```
public partial class MainView : Form, IMainView
{
    private BindingSource _bsGroups = new BindingSource();

    public MainView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        SetBindings();

        this.CenterToScreen();
        this.Text = "SimpleEvent";
    }

    private void SetBindings()
    {
        //ComboBox
        _bsGroups.DataSource = typeof(BindingList<Group>);
        _comboBox.DisplayMember = nameof(Group.Number);
        _comboBox.DataSource = _bsGroups;
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Список групп для комбобокса
    /// </summary>
    public BindingList<Group> Groups
    {
        get => _bsGroups.List as BindingList<Group>;
        set => _bsGroups.DataSource = value;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Выбранная группа
    /// </summary>
    public Group SelectedGroup => _bsGroups.Current as Group;

    /// <summary>
    /// Событие выбора в комбобоксе группа
    /// </summary>
    public SimpleEventHandler SelectedGroupChanged
    {
        set
        {
            _bsGroups.CurrentChanged += value.Handler;
        }
    }

    public void ShowMessage(string message)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(message);
    }
}
```

А презентер такой

```
public class MainPresenter
{
    private readonly IMainView _mainView;

    //ctor
    public MainPresenter(IMainView mainView)
    {
        _mainView = mainView ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(mainView));

        LoadGroups();

        //событие выбора в комбобоксе
        _mainView.SelectedGroupChanged = new SimpleEventHandler(OnSelectedGroup);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Событие выбора в комбобоксе
    /// </summary>
    private void OnSelectedGroup()
    {
        string message = $"Вы выбрали: {_mainView.SelectedGroup.Number}";
        _mainView.ShowMessage(message);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Загрузка данных для комбобокса
    /// </summary>
    private async void LoadGroups()
    {
        var groups = await Program.Repository.GetAllGroups();
        _mainView.Groups = new BindingList<Group>(groups.ToList());
    }
}
```

**2) Событые имеет значемые для презентера параметры.**
[image: пример на событие MouseDown выводятся координаты курсора мыши]

Создадим такой класс посредник

```
public class ParameterizedEventHandler
{
    private Action<Dictionary<string, object>> _handlerExecutor;

    //ctor
    public ParameterizedEventHandler(Action<Dictionary<string, object>> handlerExecutor)
    {
        _handlerExecutor = handlerExecutor ??
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(handlerExecutor));
    }

    public void RaiseEvent(Dictionary<string, object> parameters)
    {
        _handlerExecutor(parameters);
    }
}
```

Параметры в презентер будем передовать в словаре вот так

```
public partial class MainView : Form, IMainView
{
    public MainView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.CenterToScreen();
        this.Text = nameof(ParamEvent);

        //событие клика мыши по картинке
        _pictureBox.MouseClick += _pictureBox_MouseClick;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Обработка события нажатия кнопки мыши по картинке
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    private void _pictureBox_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        //собираем нужную инфо
        string mouseButton = e.Button.ToString();
        int x = e.X;
        int y = e.Y;

        //формируем параметры
        Dictionary<string, object> parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        parameters.Add(nameof(mouseButton), mouseButton);
        parameters.Add(nameof(x), x);
        parameters.Add(nameof(y), y);

        //вызываем событие и передаем эти параметры
        MouseClickEvent.RaiseEvent(parameters);
    }

    private ParameterizedEventHandler _MouseClickEvent;
    public ParameterizedEventHandler MouseClickEvent
    {
        get => _MouseClickEvent;
        set
        {
            if (_MouseClickEvent != null) return;
            _MouseClickEvent = value;
        }
    }

    public void ShowMessage(string message)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(message);
    }
}
```

Презентер такой

```
public class MainPresenter
{
    private readonly IMainView _mainView;

    //ctor
    public MainPresenter(IMainView mainView)
    {
        _mainView = mainView ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(mainView));

        //
        _mainView.MouseClickEvent = new ParameterizedEventHandler(OnMouseClick);
    }

    private void OnMouseClick(Dictionary<string, object> parameters)
    {
        string message = $"Была нажата кнопка мыши: {parameters["mouseButton"]}"
            + Environment.NewLine
            + $"Координаты курсора мыши: X={parameters["x"]}, Y={parameters["y"]}";

        _mainView.ShowMessage(message);
    }
}
```

**3) Пример на кнопки с привязкой к свойствам `Enabled` и `Text`**
[image: пример как изменяется у кнопки свойства доступности и надписи]

Для кнопки слева сделана привязка к свойству `Enabled` с помощью такого класса

```
public class SimpleButtonEventHandler : SimpleEventHandler, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private Func<bool> _setterEnableProperty;

    //ctor
    public SimpleButtonEventHandler(Action handlerExecutor) : this(handlerExecutor, null)
    {
    }
    public SimpleButtonEventHandler(Action handlerExecutor, Func<bool> setterEnableProperty) : base(handlerExecutor)
    {
        if (setterEnableProperty == null)
        {
            _setterEnableProperty = () => true;
        }
        else
        {
            _setterEnableProperty = setterEnableProperty;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Доступность кнопки для нажатия
    /// </summary>
    private bool _Enabled = true;
    public bool Enabled
    {
        get => _Enabled;
        private set
        {
            _Enabled = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Инициализация проверки доступности кнопки
    /// </summary>
    public void CheckEnabled()
    {
        Enabled = _setterEnableProperty();
    }

    //INPC
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Для кнопки справа используется привязка к свойствам `Enabled` и `Text`

```
public class TextButtonEventHandler : SimpleButtonEventHandler
{
    //ctor
    public TextButtonEventHandler(Action handlerExecutor) : base(handlerExecutor)
    { }
    public TextButtonEventHandler(Action handlerExecutor, Func<bool> setterEnableProperty) : base(handlerExecutor, setterEnableProperty)
    { }

    /// <summary>
    /// Надпись на кнопке
    /// </summary>
    private string _Text;
    public string Text
    {
        get => _Text;
        set
        {
            _Text = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

Вьюшка такая

```
public partial class MainView : Form, IMainView
{
    private BindingSource _bsButtonClick = new BindingSource();
    private BindingSource _bsButtonText = new BindingSource();

    public MainView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        SetBindings();

        this.CenterToScreen();
        this.Text = nameof(ButtonEvents);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Устанавливаем привязки
    /// </summary>
    private void SetBindings()
    {
        // Кнопка слева
        _bsButtonClick.DataSource = typeof(SimpleButtonEventHandler);
        _buttonClickOk.DataBindings.Add("Enabled", _bsButtonClick, "Enabled");

        // Кнопка справа
        _bsButtonText.DataSource = typeof(TextButtonEventHandler);
        _buttonTextOk.DataBindings.Add("Enabled", _bsButtonText, "Enabled");
        _buttonTextOk.DataBindings.Add("Text", _bsButtonText, "Text");
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Кнопка слева
    /// </summary>
    public SimpleButtonEventHandler ClickOK
    {
        get => _bsButtonClick.Current as SimpleButtonEventHandler;
        set
        {
            if (_bsButtonClick.Count > 0) return;
            _bsButtonClick.Add(value);
            _buttonClickOk.Click += value.Handler;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Лейбл отсчета кликов
    /// </summary>
    public string ClickOutput
    {
        get => _labelCount.Text;
        set => _labelCount.Text = value;
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Кнопка справа
    /// </summary>
    public TextButtonEventHandler TextOK
    {
        get => _bsButtonText.Current as TextButtonEventHandler;
        set
        {
            if (_bsButtonText.Count > 0) return;
            _bsButtonText.Add(value);
            _buttonTextOk.Click += value.Handler;
        }
    }
}
```

Презентер к ней

```
public class MainPresenter
{
    private readonly IMainView _mainView;

    private int _clickCount = 5;
    private int _clickCountText = 5;

    //ctor
    public MainPresenter(IMainView mainView)
    {
        _mainView = mainView ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(mainView));

        //Кнопка слева
        _mainView.ClickOK = new SimpleButtonEventHandler(OnClick, CanClick);
        _mainView.ClickOutput = _clickCount.ToString();//вывод в лейбл

        //Кнопка справа
        _mainView.TextOK = new TextButtonEventHandler(OnText, CanText);
        _mainView.TextOK.Text = "OK";
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Кнопка слева Доступность
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private bool CanClick()
    {
        return _clickCount > 0;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Кнопка слева обработка события клик
    /// </summary>
    private void OnClick()
    {
        --_clickCount;
        _mainView.ClickOutput = _clickCount.ToString();

        if (_clickCount == 0)
        {
            //проверить доступность кнопки, через вызов CanClick()
            _mainView.ClickOK.CheckEnabled();
        }
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Доступность кнопки справа
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private bool CanText()
    {
        return _clickCountText > 0;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Кнопка справа обработчик
    /// </summary>
    private void OnText()
    {
        --_clickCountText;
        //выводим на кнопку величину
        _mainView.TextOK.Text = _clickCountText.ToString();

        if (_clickCountText == 0)
        {
            _mainView.TextOK.Text = "Всё";
            _mainView.TextOK.CheckEnabled();
        }
    }
}
```

**4) Кнопка на `ToolStrip`**

[image: показана кнопка на панели, которая выключается, если в текстбокс нет текста]

Имеет такую особенность, что у нее изначально нет поддержки привязок. Поэтому нам понадобится такой класс унаследованный класс кнопки

```
public class ToolStripBindableButton : ToolStripButton, IBindableComponent
{
    private ControlBindingsCollection _DataBindings;
    public ControlBindingsCollection DataBindings
    {
        get => _DataBindings = _DataBindings ?? new ControlBindingsCollection(this);
    }


    private BindingContext _BindingContext;
    public BindingContext BindingContext
    {
        get => _BindingContext = _BindingContext ?? new BindingContext();
        set => _BindingContext = value;
    }
}
```

После добавления в проект такого класса и компиляции эту кнопку можно будет добавить к тулбар и работать с ней таким образом

```
public partial class MainView : Form, IMainView
{
    private BindingSource _bsTool = new BindingSource();

    public MainView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //привязка кнопки на тулбаре
        _bsTool.DataSource = typeof(SimpleButtonEventHandler);
        _toolStripBindableButton.DataBindings.Add("Enabled", _bsTool, "Enabled");

        this.CenterToScreen();
        this.Text = nameof(ToolStripEvent);
    }

    //кнопка
    public SimpleButtonEventHandler ToolButton
    {
        get => _bsTool.Current as SimpleButtonEventHandler;
        set
        {
            if (_bsTool.Count > 0) return;
            _bsTool.Add(value);
            _toolStripBindableButton.Click += value.Handler;
        }
    }

    //текстбокс событие изменения
    private SimpleEventHandler _InputTextChanged;
    public SimpleEventHandler InputTextChanged
    {
        get => _InputTextChanged;
        set
        {
            if (_InputTextChanged != null) return;
            _InputTextChanged = value;
            _textBox.TextChanged += value.Handler;
        }
    }

    //текстбокс содержимое
    public string InputText
    {
        get => _textBox.Text;
        set => _textBox.Text = value;
    }

    public void ShowMessage(string message)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(message);
    }
}
```

И презентер

```
public class MainPresenter
{
    private readonly IMainView _mainView;

    //ctor
    public MainPresenter(IMainView mainView)
    {
        _mainView = mainView ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(mainView));

        //кнопка на тулбаре
        _mainView.ToolButton = new SimpleButtonEventHandler(OnTool, CanTool);

        //изменение в текстбоксе
        _mainView.InputTextChanged = new SimpleEventHandler(OnText);

        //заставляем выкл. кнопке на тулбаре
        _mainView.ToolButton.CheckEnabled();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Кнопка на тулбаре
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private bool CanTool()
    {
        return !String.IsNullOrEmpty(_mainView.InputText);
    }
    private void OnTool()
    {
        var message = $"Вы ввели: {_mainView.InputText}";
        _mainView.ShowMessage(message);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Событие изменения текста
    /// </summary>
    private void OnText()
    {
        //заставляем вкл. или выкл. кнопке на тулбаре
        _mainView.ToolButton.CheckEnabled();
    }
}
```

Вот, пожалуй, основные примеры на обработку всевозможных событий. Ответ и так получился слишком объемным, так что пример на работу с несколькими формами вы сможете посмотреть сами скачав решение со всеми этими примерами [здесь](https://yadi.sk/d/qPe19D3uKrZmyA).

Comment: Огромное вам спасибо! Буду изучать :)

Comment: Да, пожалуйста, рад помочь.

Comment: я извиняюсь, а можно как то связаться с вами?) очень хотелось бы обсудить один момент

Comment: а какой момент, можно подробнее?

Comment: я сделал по вашим примерам программку (одна кнопка, один текстбокс). Все работает. По клику на кнопку появляется форма, при изменении поля, в лэйбл заводится его текст. У меня получилось, что в Presener'e (как в примере выше) у меня остался пустой метод, который необходимо поместить в SimpleEventHandler в качестве параметра. Правильно ли это? Код положил на битбакет https://bitbucket.org/aaron-vault/eventmouseclickmvp/src

Comment: Я клонировал ваш проект, вот только никак не возьму в толк, чего вы хотите в конченом итоге сделать. Что должно произойти при нажатии на кнопку?

Comment: В этом проекте все работает (и вызов формы 2, и событие при изменении текстового поля), мне не понятно правильно ли реализовал эти два действия. Но судя по тому, что у меня в презентере пустой метод, который передается в SimpleButtonEventHandler, я не думаю, что все получилось так как надо.Не понятно вообще почему передает пустой метод, и все при этом работает

Comment: Я переделал ваш проект, почитайте комментарии. И классы ивентхендлеров менять не надо! Тем более впихивать в них ссылки на формы. Эти классы готовые кирпичики для построения программ, их не надо менять, их просто надо использовать. Коммит мне сделать в вашем проекте не удалось из-за ошибки доступа к какому-то локфайлу SQLite. Так что качайте [отсюда](https://yadi.sk/d/vKKEBtTGj5uz8A).

Comment: Я же ясно в комментариях написал: если не нужна такая привязка уберите ее совсем, т.е. удалите эту строку полностью